# I am not able to understand why my function fails - it has to be something to do with parseUser function

Tags: python

This pet project is about creating a miniature ChatServer and Client. The assumptions go like this:

First the client tries to login and then validates his details which is written using tkinter. The second frame which interacts with the user is  the chat widow. This consummates the client side.

It is presumed that the details of each user is stored in a sqlite db.

The server on the other hand first creates(spawns) a socket and assigns it to each user and keeps him logged in.

When the second user is logged in and tries to chat with the first the server validates the second user and socket pairs both of the users.

I have written a code here for the server to do the above activity but it fails for some reason. I get the following error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/CGDELL23/ChatServer/ChatServer.py', wdir='C:/Users/CGDELL23/ChatServer')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\CGDELL23\ChatServer\ChatServer.py", line 18, in <module>
    __main__

NameError: name '__main__' is not defined
```

I think it is failing in the `parseUserData` function - Can you please help

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Aug 14 10:00:54 2020

@author: Sathya Devarakonda

@Module: ChatServer.py
"""

#import networkX
import socket

import sqlite3
#from sqlite3 import error

import sys

__main__

#Network Variables
cSocket,sSocket = None

#Client socket Info
(cStrBuffer,cAncData,cflags,cAddr) = None

#Boolean Variables
validUser = None

#Arrays
newUser = []

#Variables
user,password,activityType,rUser,cUser, nullUser,nullPassword,x,y = None

#DB Connection con
con = None# Connection


class ChatServer:  
    def spawnSocket():
        sSocket.listen()
        cSocket = sSocket.accept()
        cSocket.connect()#Connection Established
        return cSocket;

    def closeSocket(cSocket):
        cSocket.close
        
    def parseUserData(cStrBuffer):
        return cStrBuffer.split(',')
        
            
    def disconnectUser(cUser):
        DBCalls.deleteUser(cUser)

    def validateUser(cSocket):
        (cStrBuffer, cAncdata, cFlags, cAddr)  = cSocket.recvmsg(1024)
        (activityType,user,password,cUser) = parseUserData(cStrBuffer)
        if (activityType == 'login'):
            return(cUser)
    
    def connectrUser(cSocket,rUser):
        try:
            rSocket = DBCalls.getUser(rUser)
            #(rStrBuffer,rAncdata, rFlags, rAddr) = rSocket.recvmsg(1024)
            socket.socketpair(cSocket,rSocket)
        except socket.err as err:
            print ('Creation of socket Failed')
            sys.settrace()
        except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
            print ('Db query Failed')
            sys.settrace()

    def chatUser(cUser):
        (cStrBuffer, cAncdata, cFlags, cAddr)  = cSocket.recvmsg(1024)
        (activityType,user,passsword,rUser) = parseUserData(cStrBuffer)
        if(activityType ==  'chat'):
            connectrUser(cSocket,rUser)   
        elif (activityType == 'logoff'):
            disconnectUser(rUser)
    
    def validateLoop():       
        try:  
            #Creating a Server Socket and binding it to localhost
            sSocket = socket.socket(-1,-1,-1,None)
            sSocket.bind("127.0.0.1")
        
            while(True):
                cSocket = spawnSocket()
                cUser = validateUser(cSocket)
                if (cUser):
                    chatUser(cUser)
        
        except socket.err as err:
                print ('Creation of socket Failed')
                sys.settrace()

    
            
class DBCalls:

    def createConn():
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('SockDetails')
        except socket.error as error:
            print ('Creation of connection failed')
            sys.settrace()
            
    def closeConn():
        try:
            con = sqlite3.close()
        except socket.error as error:
            print ('Closing connection failed')
            sys.settrace()
        
    def insertUser(cUser,cSocket,cAddr):
        try:
            userCursor =  con.cursor()
            userCursor.execute('insert into SockDetails (cUser,cSocket,cAddr)')
            con.commit
        except socket.error as error:
            print ('Error adding socket details')
            sys.settrace()
        finally:
            return (True)
        
    def checkUser(rUser):
        userIn = False #Boolean Flag    
        try:
            userCursor =  con.cursor()
            userCursor.execute('select * from SockDetails where user=cUser')
            con.commit                
        except socket.error as error:
            print ('Error checking socket details')
            sys.settrace()    
        return (userIn)
    
    def getUser(cUser):
        rSocket = False
        try:
            userCursor =  con.cursor()
            userCursor.execute('select socket from SockDetails where user=cUser')
            con.commit                
        except socket.error as error:
            print ('Error adding socket details')
            sys.settrace()    
        finally:
            return (rSocket)
    
    def deleteUser(cUser):
        try:
            userCursor =  con.cursor()
            userCursor.execute('delete * from SockDetails where user=rUser')
            con.commit                
        except socket.error as error:
            print ('Error delete socket details')
            sys.settrace()    
        finally:
            return (True)
```

Comment: There is nothing called `__main__` in python, but there is `__name__`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of :

```
import sys
__main__
```

try to use:

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__": # in python main used like this way
    "Rest of Code"
```

Comment: I am still working on these - I will post the working code soon - Kindly ignore the edits